# Delphi dictionary freeing

Tags: delphi, dictionary, memory-leaks, tdictionary

I implemented the following class:

```
type
  TUtilProcedure = procedure(var AJsonValue: TJSONObject);

  TCallback = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FProcedure: TUtilProcedure;
    FAnnotation: string;
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string; AProcedure: TUtilProcedure; AAnnotation: string); overload;
    constructor Create(ACallback: TCallback); overload;
    property Name: string read FName;
    property Proc: TUtilProcedure read FProcedure;
    property Annotation: string read FAnnotation;
 end;
```

Then I have a global variable:

```
procedures: TDictionary<string, TCallback>;
```

In `OnFormActivate` procedure I initalize the `procedures` variable:

```
procedures := TDictionary<string, TCallback>.Create();
procedures.Add('something', TCallback.Create('sth', @proc, 'annotation')); 
// ....
```

And then in `OnFormClose` I free it:

```
procedures.Clear;
procedures.Free;
```

Does my code leak memory? If so what is the correct way to free the `dictionary`?
From what I know iteration is not good idea.

Comment: Use  a `TObjectDictionary` when using objects if you want to automatically free the values, use the `[doOwnsValues]` when creating the dictionary

Comment: Does `TCallback` need a `destructor`

Comment: `TCallback` does not need a destructor right now

Comment: @fantaghirocco thank you

Comment: Don't use `@` with procedures. That suppresses the compiler's type safety. Enable the typed address compiler option that Embarcadero still refuse to enable, and in doing so make all Delphi beginners suffer needlessly.

Comment: A bigger question would be why you use a global variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code leaks memory because the objects contained in a `TDictionary` are not automatically freed.

If you need to store objects in a dictionary, the adoption of a [TObjectDictionary](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectDictionary) represents a better approach.

If you want the objects contained in the dictionary to be automatically freed, use the `doOwnsValues` flag while creating the instance of the collection.

- *When the variable is really global* (i.e. is declared under `var` in the `interface` section of the unit), it should be created and destroyed in the `initialization` and `finalization` section of the unit itself.

  ```
  . . .
  var
    procedures: TObjectDictionary<string, TCallback>;
  . . .
  initialization
    procedures:= TObjectDictionary<string, TCallback>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
  finalization
    procedures.Free;
  ```
- *When your variable belongs to the form class itself*, you should create the dictionary in the form's `OnCreate` event.

  ```
  . . .
  public
    procedures: TObjectDictionary<string, TCallback>;
  . . .
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    procedures:= TObjectDictionary<string, TCallback>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
  end;
  ```

  Free the dictionary in the form's `OnDestroy` event:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    procedures.Free;
  end;
  ```
- Furthermore, if you want the variable belonging to the class to be accessed without the need of an instance of the class itself (this is referred as a *static variable* in many programming languages), you can declare the dictionary as a `class var` and optionally access it through a `class property`; in such a case, it's better to create and destroy the collection in the `class constructor` and in the `class destructor`.

  ```
  . . .
  TMyClass = class
    private
      class constructor Create;
      class destructor Destoy;
    public
      class var procedures: TObjectDictionary<string, TCallback>;
  end;
  . . .
  class constructor TMyClass.Create;
  begin
    procedures := TObjectDictionary<string, TCallback>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
  end;

  class destructor TMyClass.Destoy;
  begin
    procedures.Free;
  end;
  ```

---

```
TCallback = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FProcedure: TUtilProcedure;
    FAnnotation: string;
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string; AProcedure: TUtilProcedure; AAnnotation: string); overload;
    constructor Create(ACallback: TCallback); overload;
    property Name: string read FName;
    property Proc: TUtilProcedure read FProcedure;
    property Annotation: string read FAnnotation;
end;
```

As a side note, the `TCallback` class does not need to specify a destructor because only owns two strings and a pointer to a procedure. And so the default destructor inherited from `TObject` suffices.

Comment: That is fine for this case, where there is only one instance of the form. If there are more than instances of the form, using FormCreate and FormDestroy to construct or destroy such a variable may not be so good. But OTOH, using global variables is not recommendable anyway.

Comment: Hmmm... If the variable must really be global, for some reason or other, why not construct and destroy it in the initialization and finalization sections, respectively?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis thank you for your comments: I have updated the answer according to your remarks; the multiple form instance issue was already pointed out by @David Heffernan, but I wrongly assumed too quickly that the *global* variable could have been a `private` one